# Python interactive mode no longer works in powershell

Tags: python, powershell

So after having to specify paths to the Powershell in order for pip to work correctly and after entering some incorrect setx commands the interactive mode in Powershell no longer works. Python is not recognized as a function in Powershell. I unistalled python and reinstalled it to no avail. Any ideas? I was trying to set a path: setx PATH "%PATH%C:\python27\lib\site-packages\regetron but I forgot to close the command with a ". Could this have been the problem. Also I copy pasted the original command from the net without realizing it was for python 3 as in python34\lib\site-packages. Could this have caused issues?

Comment: In Powershell, execute `$env:path` and `$env:path -split ';'`. Are there any syntax errors, like missing semicolon?